# Discord.py - Restart Command Error - RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently working on a discord bot. I was working on the restart command.

I checked on discord to see if it work, but I get this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000245FCC9C280>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x00000245FD9BB100>
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x00000245FCC9C280>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

My Code

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')
client.remove_command('help')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Ready')

@client.event
async def on_connect():

    Online = discord.Embed(title='Online', color=discord.Color.green())
    Online.set_author(name="Bot Status")

@client.event
async def on_disconnect():

    Offline = discord.Embed(title='Offline', color=discord.Color.red())
    Offline.set_author(name="Bot Status")

@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=9999):
    await ctx.send("Fetching messages...", delete_after=2.0)
    await asyncio.sleep(2.0)
    await ctx.send(content="Deleting messages...", delete_after=2.0)
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount + 1) 
    await ctx.send(f"Done! {amount} message(s) deleted.", delete_after=10.0) 
    return

@client.command()
async def restart(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Restarting...', delete_after=4.0)
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('')
    await ctx.Bot.logout()
    await client.login("Token", bot=True)
    await ctx.send('Done!', delete_after=5.0)

client.run('Token', bot=True, reconnect=True)
```

I change it but it is the same thing every time. So can someone help me figure it out? Thank for all your answers!

I use Python 3.9.1
VS Code

Comment: You're going to want to [regenerate your bot's token](https://discord.com/developers/applications). It's been edited out, but it's going to stay in the edit revisions.

Comment: Forgot to hide token. Thx! Just regenerated it

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ctx.bot.login(...)`?

Comment: no it doesn't work

Comment: Then what is `login` referring to? Show all your code

Comment: @ZeRuiZheng are you starting your bot with [`bot.run`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.run)? If so, it takes care of creating the async event loop, so when you call `logout`, the event loop is closed, hence the "Event loop is closed" error you're getting. If you want to be able to "restart", then you'll have to manage your own event loop.

Comment: I edit the code so it much clear

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340248/discord-py-how-to-fix-event-loop-is-closed ?

Comment: @Christian Yes I did but this is more complicated

Comment: hide your bot's token,

Comment: yes yes yes I know I keep forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`discord.ext.commands.Bot.logout`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.logout) and [`discord.ext.commands.Bot.login`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.login),

```
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def restart(ctx):
    await ctx.bot.logout()
    await client.login("your_token", bot=True)
```

Comment: no it still same thing but it kinda works